Python Object and Metaclass
i am new in python and having some confusions. As Java, in python also it is showing that Object is the top-most class but then what is the use of Metaclass as it is showing that all classes are objects of Metaclass.
I am getting confused to grsap it.
Please help
I am trying to clear my concept on Metaclass and Object class.

Metaclasses and superclasses are different concepts. Metaclass is the class of the class.

Don't try too hard to grasp it - there is a "paradox" there, indeed.
object being a class in Python has a metaclass, and it is type: type is the default metaclass for everything.
But, being a class, type is also a subclass of object. And also, as  type needs a metaclass itself, that metaclass is also type: it is its own metaclass.
These relationships are possible becuse type and object are wired like so in the source code in C for Python itself: one can't establish similar relationships for user defined classes.
It is not too important to  understand that completely - the important thing to understand is that a "metaclass"  relationship - the "class of a class" is not the same as a "superclass" or inheritance: these are ortogonal concepts, and one can live a whole life as a programmer without ever touching the metaclass concept.

In [24]: object.__mro__
Out[24]: (object,)

In [25]: type.__mro__
Out[25]: (type, object)

In [26]: type(object)
Out[26]: type

In [27]: type(type)
Out[27]: type

